# Ordinal binary numbers

Tags: regex

I wanna match ordinal binary numbers from 0 to 15, these numbers are written in a consecutive manner (*no spaces between actually*):

```
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

I need a very short way of using expressions to achieve this and it should match it as it is! I mean the matching domain! nothing more! I don't want to match a similar one:

```
0000 0010 0001 0011 0100 0110 0101 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

Which I tried is `((00)[01]{2}){4}((01)[01]{2}){4}((10)[01]{2}){4}((11)[01]{2}){4}`

I know that it's not accurate thus I asked it here.

Comment: Ah the *long count* challenge from this [Regex Golf](http://regex.alf.nu) ... FYI, there is no need to match the whole expression. Actually that's the trick to gain more points :)

Comment: why you want use regex when is easier use string.Split() ?

Comment: It's regex.alf.nu, right? My solution was either very short and not matching binaries specifically (for Long count) and a bit longer for v2, one could say very similar to the string to match =P

Comment: I'm not playing, I saw it before and yet complaining how to solve it. I can expand my regex but I don't like nasty regular expressions!

Comment: @FelicePollano that's all about regexes man!

Comment: @revo There's really no way to match such things, and it'll be a very literal regex really, except for a few parts maybe.

Comment: @Jerry maybe you're right! but I like challenges!

Comment: @revo Well, the really shortest regex to match what you want to match and no other string with binary numbers in different order is `0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111` or `0{4} 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1{4}` which are of the same length, and there's no way those will fail.

Comment: @Jerry with no spaces between, what you can do?

Comment: @Jerry How about 2 characters shorter? check the answer. _Now I can sleep comfortably_

Comment: Jerry, you need to encase your pattern in `^` and `$` if you really want it to match no other string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a short regex that matches the given string, but does not match any string of the same form where the binary numbers are reordered.  This regex does not satisfy that, but it at least solves the "Long Count" puzzle from http://regex.alf.nu :

```
((\d+)0 \2[1] ?){8}
```

Comment: Great solution to the riddle - definitely shorter than my method. I didn't think of such way to relax the condition based on the input.

Comment: Nice solution but as you said it has many other match domain cases.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will serve as a **hint** to solve this riddle with much less characters that the string to be matched.

This solution relies heavily on the assumptions that **all the binary numbers are fixed width** (in this case is 4-bit).

Instead of directly counting the numbers up, we will try to compare 2 adjacent numbers.

Let us *assume for now that we are at the beginning of a binary number* (not somewhere arbitrary). We want the number in front to compare strictly less than the number behind.

To compare 2 binary numbers with **fixed width**, we can just go from left to right and remove similar digit, until all digits have been removed (equal) or there is a difference. Since the number in front is strictly less, there must be a difference, where the number in front is 0 and the number behind is 1 at the same bit. We can write a zero-width look-ahead assertion for this:

```
(?=([01]*)0[01]* (\1)1)
```

(The parentheses around `\1` is needed, at least in JavaScript, to prevent formation of octal escape sequence `\11`).

To remove the assumption that we are at the beginning of a binary number, we only need to add anchors, and consume characters so that we end up at the beginning of the next number.

```
^(?=([01]*)0[01]* (\1)1)....[ ]
```

Since we have already assert the increasing order of the numbers, we only need to assert the number of binary numbers through the repetition.

```
^(?:(?=([01]*)0[01]* (\1)1).... ){15}1111$
```

This problem can be extended to asserting a string consisting of 2^n fixed-width n-bit-wide binary string is strictly increasing. It can also be used to assert a sequence of fixed-width binary number is increasing. The technique may also be applied to asserting words listed in lexicographic order or not, although the regex will be quite long.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\60){7}(100)(\2\1)(110)\3(101)01\2(111)\3(\2\4)\5\1\6\7\6\5\6
```

So I did it! Long time on this regular expression with 62 characters length, which is 2 characters less than the string itself.

Live demo: http://regex101.com/r/nN5uH0

Comment: Your regex simply will not pass the test case on regex.alf.nu, since spaces needs to be matched.

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't do anything with that website!